# Show the background image location (http://www...) in textbox HTML JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website allow users to change the background image using a URL with the following code:

```
var defaultImage = "'#fff'";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('back') ? "url('" + localStorage.getItem('back') + "')" : "url('" + defaultImage + "')";

function changebackground() {
    var url = document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
    localStorage.setItem('back', url);
}
```

I was wondering how can the current background image URL be displayed in a textbox?

DEMO: http://goo.gl/253IN

**UPDATE:**
This is what I would like:

```
function changebackground() {
    var url = document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";

    // populate the input w/ the url:
    document.getElementById('textfield').value = url;    

    localStorage.setItem('back', url);
}
```

However every time the page refreshes the textbox is clear. How can I save this information so it always stays in the textbox even when the page is refreshed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `var bgimage = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage; txtbox.value =  bgimage.replace(/^url\('/, "").replace(/'\)$/, "");` - http://jsfiddle.net/KW852/

Comment: You can use `document.body.style...`. No need to get by tag name.

Comment: thank you @Ian how can I implement this in a textbox?

Comment: thanks @jimjimmy1995 but Im not sure what you mean

Comment: @GioL Replace `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` with `document.body`. Probably doesn't fix anything but is easier to write and nicer to look at.

Comment: @GioL http://jsfiddle.net/KW852/2/

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 And it's definitely faster

Comment: @Ian Exactly! No traversing the DOM.

Comment: @Ian I will try your method now :D

Comment: @GioL No problem, I added an answer that encompasses the methodology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the background image like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var bgimage = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
    var cleaned = bgimage.replace(/^url\('/, "").replace(/'\)$/, "");
    var txtbox = document.getElementById("txt1");
    txtbox.value = cleaned || "No background image set";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KW852/3/

It gets the body's `backgroundImage` style, then strips any leading `url('` and trailing `')` and returns the middle text. Then, just sets the textbox's value.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function changebackground() {
    var url = document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;

    // populate the input w/ the url:
    setBackground(url);

    localStorage.setItem('back', url);
}

function setBackground(url){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
    setText(url);
}

function setText(url){
    document.getElementById('textfield').value = url;
}

var defaultImage = "'#fff'";
    bgUrl = localStorage.getItem('back') ? localStorage.getItem('back') : defaultImage;

// Set background
setBackground(bgUrl);
```

The only thing I added was the comment line and the line immediately following it.  You already have the URL, it's just a matter of setting the input element's value.

**Update**

I added some code to initialize the text box when the background is first set (presumably on page load), per your additional requirement in your comment, below.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is what I would like but is it possible for it to always stay in the textbox even when the page is refreshed? :)

Comment: That's useful information to include in the original question.  I will update my answer.

Comment: I cleaned up the code some more, to accomodate your follow-up request and to reduce repetitive code.

Comment: Downvoter, please speak up.  Also please read the FAQ on down-voting, I don't believe this answer comes close to deserving it: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Thanks but it still does the same thing, I have updated the demo and put in your code. It works but doesn't save the data.

Comment: Save how?  Your question says *nothing* about saving data.

Comment: Thanks for taking my code and adding it to your question.  It's customary on Stackoverflow to up-vote answers you've found useful.  What's more it will encourage people to help you further.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!! I found a different method :D I found your post really useful! I would also extremely appreciate it if you found my question useful